# Fluent NHibernate mapping a composite ID from inherited composite IDs

Tags: inheritance, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, composite-key, composite-id

Let's say I have an existing database with the following 3 tables:

Table1:
(PK)T1ID1
(PK)T1ID2

Table2:
(PK)T2ID1

Table3:
(FK)T1ID1
(FK)T1ID2
(FK)T2ID1
(Where the 3 keys come from the tables above)

**My question is: How do I map Table3 with Fluent NHibernate?**
What is confusing to me is what to do about the fact that its composite keys come from 2 different tables.

I have the following for the mappings for tables 1 and 2:

```
public class Table1
{
    public virtual long T1ID1 { get; set; }
    public virtual long T1ID2 { get; set; }
}

public class Table2
{
    public virtual long T2ID1 { get; set; }
}

public class Table1Map
{
    public Table1Map()
    {
        Table("Table1");

        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.T1ID1, "T1ID1")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.T1ID2, "T1ID2");
    }
}

public class Table2Map
{
    public Table2Map()
    {
        Table("Table2");

        Id(x => x.T2ID1, "T2ID1");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having some pain just trying to map a m:n with both tables composite pk. seemingly not even as edge as your case. Any luck?

Answer (score 1):

try looking at [Fluent NHibernate and composite ID with single column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581418/fluent-nhibernate-and-composite-id-with-single-column-name)
I think what you're after is the ".KeyReference()" property.
The link above is using an old version of FNH but all you need to be concerned with , with regards to your issue is that the method names are slightly different. all the rest of that article should help you.

Let me know how you go.